# API 4.3 - Support Library - do i need HoloEverywhere?

Tags: android, android-actionbar, android-support-library

i just read that the new Support Library has ActionBar implemented, that is quite cool, but does it also replace HoloEverywhere? If not, it is possible to use HoloEverywhere with the support ActionBar instead of ActionBarSherlock?

If thats not possible it is quite senseless, that they integrated ActionBar, almost everyone using ActionBarSherlock uses it combined with HoloEverywhere, and they would still need ActionBarSherlock.

Metin

Comment: The concept of `HoloEverywhere` is to be applied to the whole views, not only to action bar. It's a theme family, not an ActionBar theme only.

Comment: ok thanks, than it is a big fail from google, nobody will use it :), theyre all using sherlock+holo, but maybe holoeverywhere will adapt to use ActionBarCompat in near future

Comment: Why `nobody will use it`? holo is a styling thing ... ActionBar is a visual component that can be stylized however you wish to. holoeverywhere is a style guideline. I think these two are separate things.

Comment: if not nobody, then almost nobody :), i think most people use them together, but sure not all